# In Pm2 cluster mode the global variable has different value for each thread

Tags: node.js, pm2, cluster-mode

I have a NodeJs application which is running in cluster mode with 4 instance. 
A map is defined in a file "pipeline.js" like below :

```
var map = new Map();
module.exports = map;
```

I entered value in map like below :

```
map[value] = value_1;
```

In the code I have to remove the value from map but it gives error saying :

```
map[value] is empty.
```

But when rum with only 1 instance this error doesn't appear.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Make use of external storage if you want to share information across each cluster. Something like node-redis. 
```https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis```